Data categorization
I have categorized my education dataset for the analysis below. However, I have one occurrence of a respondent who attended a Missionary school that I do not know its level and I am unsure where to place them. Should I leave them out, and on what basis to support my decision?
Education    Yes No Total
Tertiary    22  13  35
Secondary   144 47  191
Primary     103 52  155
No education 23 13  36


Impossible to say, as depending on the context, missionary education may be at primary, secondary, or even higher education levels. You could recontact the respondent to get the information, or alternatively investigate about the story of mission schools in the country where the respondent comes from (e.g. if there were no mission schools providing secondary or higher education at the time they were studying, you can deduce it was primary education). But if you can't get more information, treating it as a non-response could be an option.

Thank you for the advice.

@J-J-J That seems like an answer to me.

@PeterFlom done, thanks for the suggestion.

As mentioned in comments, this is impossible to say, as depending on the context, missionary education may be at primary, secondary, or even higher education levels (though I'm not sure if it's common for people to refer to missionary higher education institutions as "schools", but who knows).
As a remedy, you could recontact the respondent to get the information, or alternatively investigate about the history of mission schools in the country where the respondent comes from (e.g. if there were no mission schools providing secondary or higher education at the time they were studying there, you can deduce it was primary education). But if you can't get more information, treating it as a non-response could be an option.
Note that, generally speaking, "treating it as a non-response" does not necessarily mean removing completely the observation(s) from the dataset (which is referred to as "complete case analysis"). Imputation is an alternative. I'd recommend Stef van Buuren's Flexible Imputation of Missing data as a nice reference on the subject, if you're interested. In your situation, there might be an argument that a complete case analysis is defensible as there's a single one missing observation, but it may be informative to see how imputation possibly changes your conclusions compared to a complete case analysis (though I strongly suspect that given your data, a single observation shouldn't have a radical impact on the results). Other people may have more specific comments about that.

As an aside, it looks like you've alredy decided on the coding of education levels in your study; but if you don't already know that, there are some existing standards for coding education levels that you could find interesting (be it for this study, or a future one). In particular, the International Standard Classification of Education is a prominent one, but you can find a few others on surveycodings.org. Perhaps there are also other relevant local standards, depending on the country you're studying and your field of research.

Very helpful indeed. Thank you very much.

@AmeliaNicodemus You're welcome. I'm not sure what was the "yes/no" question about; but as one of your respondents mentioned "mission school" in the question about education, it might be suggestive that the type of educational institution has also an impact on your variable of interest, not just the educational level. That might be something interesting to investigate in future studies related to your current study, if you haven't already considered that.

my dependent variable is indigenous knwoledge, my solution as you have advised earlier will be to recontact them again, if I do not succeed I will then treat it as a non-rensponse. For this research, the interest is to see how education shape IK at a sort of more general level (and not how different types of education shapes its distribution),though that indeed could be something interesting to investigate.
